# How can I create this kinda layout in android studio

Tags: java, android

[image: 1]

I'm not sure how to get image from image picker and add to a recycler view I'm pretty sure we can use recycler view for the images list and not sure how to make 1st image as cover image

Comment: Add path to its file in the xml layout file, or if youre loading from URL file, load it with AsyncBackgroundTask

Comment: Your picker needs to return a reference to the image (like a URI). You need to pass that to your ``RecyclerView``'s adapter, so it can add it to the current list of image URIs and update. `onBindViewHolder` (where each item in the ``RecyclerView`` gets displayed) needs to load the image from the URI into an `ImageView`, e.g. using something like *Glide*: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/ You probably need a ``GridLayoutManager`` for your `RecyclerView` too (or if you just want them in a line, a ``LinearLayoutManager`` with `orientation` set to `HORIZONTAL`)

Comment: Thanks both of you I get it but what about the cover picture thing